# Why does my Cypher query not work?

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

I am making a Node.js server which manipulates a Neo4j database. Now I have a system of admins and posts, admins add posts. This is currently what my graph looks like:

[image: data model]

Now I want the network to be interconnected so I want to add a relationship between the Admin nodes "COLLEAGUE_OF". I wrote a Cypher query but I am getting a Cypher syntax error.

This is the syntax:

```
MERGE (c:Admin) 
MERGE (n:BlogPost {mongoId:{idNeo}}) 
MERGE (b:Admin {mongoAdminId:{idNeoAd}}) 
MERGE(n)-[:ADDED_BY]->(b), (b)-[:COLLUEGE_OF]->(c)
```

This is the entire route which executes the syntax:

```
routes.post('/blogPosts/frontpage/:id/:aid', function (req, res) {
  const id = req.param('id');
  const aid = req.param('aid');

    session
    .run("MERGE (c:Admin) MERGE (n:BlogPost {mongoId:{idNeo}}) MERGE (b:Admin {mongoAdminId:{idNeoAd}}) MERGE(n)-[:ADDED_BY]->(b), (b)-[:COLLUEGE_OF]->(c)", {idNeo: id, idNeoAd: aid})
    .then(function(result) {
      res.status(200).json({"response": "BlogPost added to front page."});
      session.close();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(400).json(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: Your first MERGE on `c` will match it to every :Admin node in the graph, and subsequently will connect every :Admin node to the `b` :Admin node (and if `b` already exists it will connect `b` to itself as well). Is that really what you want? Also, I'm guessing you want the relationship to be :COLLEAGUE_OF?

Comment: @InverseFalcon What I want is for every new admin added to be COLLUEGE_OF every other existing admin. How can I change this query to do that?

Comment: I'm just wondering if that's something that's useful. Are there going to be any :Admin nodes that aren't colleagues with each other? Are there any :COLLEAGUE_OF relationships in the graph (or planned for the graph) that connect to other kinds of nodes? What kinds of queries are you planning to write where that relationship will be traversed, and what makes that better than matching to all :Admin nodes and filtering?

Comment: If you are just trying to add COLLUEGE_OF relationships between Admin nodes, why reference BlogPost at all?

Comment: @InverseFalcon It is indeed not usefull, but I made this system and for my project I need to have interconnected relationships and this seems like a simple way of doing it.

Comment: @zachdb86 Because in the query I also add the blogpost which the admin has added to the front page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that :COLLUEGE_OF is the spelling you want (if this is in English, you may want :COLLEAGUE_OF instead), this query should take an existing graph of :Admin nodes and connect them to each other:

```
MATCH (c:Admin)
WITH collect(c) as admins
UNWIND admins as admin1
UNWIND admins as admin2
WITH admin1, admin2
WHERE id(admin1) < id(admin2) // prevents matching to the same pair with swapped order, and matching a node to itself
MERGE (admin1)-[:COLLUEGE_OF]-(admin2)
```

And this query would be used when adding a new blogpost and admin to the graph (it will not perform the merge if it has previously been processed):

```
MERGE (n:BlogPost {mongoId:{idNeo}}) 
MERGE (b:Admin {mongoAdminId:{idNeoAd}}) 
MERGE (n)-[:ADDED_BY]->(b)
WITH b
WHERE NOT (b)-[:COLLUEGE_OF]-()
MATCH (c:Admin)
WHERE c <> b
MERGE (b)-[:COLLUEGE_OF]-(c)
```

That said, if you really need :Admins to be connected to each other, it would be far easier to model this differently, with some kind of :ColleagueGroup node that all :Admins connect to, like this:

```
// create the single :ColleagueGroup node for all admins:
MERGE (group:ColleagueGroup)
WITH group
MATCH (c:Admin)
MERGE (c)-[:COLLUEGE_OF]->(group)
```

And then for adding a new admin

```
// add a new :Admin to the group
MERGE (n:BlogPost {mongoId:{idNeo}}) 
MERGE (b:Admin {mongoAdminId:{idNeoAd}})
WITH n, b 
MATCH (group:ColleagueGroup)
MERGE (n)-[:ADDED_BY]->(b)
MERGE (b)-[:COLLUEGE_OF]->(group)
```

And for finding colleagues of a single :Admin node (which will be all :Admins):

```
MATCH (b:Admin {mongoAdminId:{idNeoAd}})-[:COLLUEGE_OF*2]-(colleague:Admin)
RETURN colleague
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the last line of your query, specifically, the `, (b)-[:COLLUEGE_OF]->(c)` statement, which creates a syntax error. Just remove the comma and add an additional merge statement.

```
MERGE (c:Admin) 
MERGE (n:BlogPost {mongoId:{idNeo}}) 
MERGE (b:Admin {mongoAdminId:{idNeoAd}}) 
MERGE(n)-[:ADDED_BY]->(b)
MERGE(b)-[:COLLUEGE_OF]->(c)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked. Now is there a way I can exclude the relation to itself? It now says Admin x is a colleague of Admin x.